# Merging multiple line feature into single feature using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, merge

How do I merge multiple line feature into a single feature automatically using ArcMap?

Can only be selected and combined. It doesn't dissolve.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the lines are topologically connected then you could do a Merge or Append. Alternatively, you could select all the lines and then do a Merge (not the geoprocessing tool), but if you're in editing mode then you can Merge them that way.